# Remember me not working

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

In my symfony2 application, I am trying to log in users with the "Remember me" functionality enabled by default. The cookie is set correctly but the user is logged out nonetheless after some time (I'd say something around an hour). This happens on my development machine, staging and production version.

The security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    default:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: frontend_user_login
            check_path: frontend_user_loginCheck
            username_parameter: user[email]
            password_parameter: user[password]
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path: frontend_user_logout
        remember_me:
             key: "%secret%"
             lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
             path: /
             domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

The config.yml:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 31536000
        cookie_httponly: true
        handler_id: ~
        name: mycookie
```

Looking at my cookie in Chrome, it shows me:

```
Name:   mycookie
Content:    hqafha2ut4rpl4bdnh2jhcfm34
Domain: REPLACED
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   No (HttpOnly)
Created:    Thursday, January 8, 2015 at 10:46:36 PM
Expires:    Friday, January 8, 2016 at 10:46:36 PM
```

I am storing my sessions in redis using the `session.save_handler = redis` setting in my php.ini. The problem did exist before I switched to redis and didn't change in the process, so I don't think that's the problem?

Is there anything else I am missing? Might there be some php.ini configuration I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer from Jay worked for me, I'd like to answer my own question and go into detail about all the different configurations for both remember me and session lifetime.

**REMEMBER ME**

There is a `remember_me` key for the `login_form` (see my question above), but it doesn't do what I though it would. I am still not sure what it really does, but it doesn't mean that the login is always assumed to be with remember_me activated.

Instead, putting `always_remember_me: true` to your `remember_me` configuration in the `security.yml` did the trick. A second cookie, named `REMEMBERME` is created and used to log a user in if the session times out.

Adding a hidden input field with name `_remember_me` and value `1` works as well.

**SESSION LIFETIME**

To change the session lifetime within your symfony application, you can either change the values in the php.ini directly or define those in the `config.yml`.

Both ways, the value you need to edit is `gc_maxlifetime`. Change the value in the php.ini or add it to the `framework` -> `session` section in your `config.yml` as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#gc-maxlifetime

I opted for changing the value in my config because this keeps it the same for dev/staging/production and I don't need to mess with different `php.ini` files.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line will help you (just add it to your login form):

```
// ../path/to/login.html.twig

<input type="hidden" name="_remember_me" value="1" />
```